# Configuring Git in XCode4 shows "Host is unreachable"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, git, xcode4

I am trying to configure Git repository using Xcode 4.

When I try to enter path in 'Location', it shows "Host is unreachable".
eventhough I am able to access the same path thru Finder.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I got my mistake.

In filepath I was entering as:
smb://computername/foldername/

But instead, we should give as:
/Volumes/foldername/

Doing it this way gave "Host reachable".

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: If you are getting the same error but using an IP address, see this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748387/xcode4-add-repository-host-unreachable/6824493#6824493]

Comment: @Josh, Thanks for sharing another solution with me...really appreciated..+1