# XCode 4.2 does not connect properly to SVN

Tags: xcode, svn

After upgrading my XCode to the gtiven version in title I am not able to connect properly to my repository anymore. If I open the organizer and switch to repositories, then the latest actions related to my repositorywill be shown. But if I want to check Root or one of the smartlinks added due to checkouts then I get "unable to load revision history". During the whole process a red status icon is shown next to my repository.

I searched around and got some hints to solve as shown below:

[XCode4 add Repository Host Unreachable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748387/xcode4-add-repository-host-unreachable)
Does not do the trick because I already use the hostname instead of the ip.

[After upgraded to Xcode 4.2, Organizer - SVN repository stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203553/after-upgraded-to-xcode-4-2-organizer-svn-repository-stopped-working)
The current release version of XCode is 4.2 Build 4C199 and there this mentioned bug is not fixed. Downgrading to a beta version (I wonder if it still is available) is not an option for me.

I have also read about a svn checkout via console to flush possibly wrong cached connection parameters but checkout via console works fine and XCode still cannot establish repository connection.

Hopefully there are some more tricks I could try to finally get rid of this mess. Otherwise I have to wait if Apple releases a newer XCode version and fixes the mentioned bug:
https://devforums.apple.com/thread/126263?tstart=0

Comment: I've got the same version and I've been trying ALL DAY to get the SVN working. I have read everything on the internet and tried a million different 'fixes'. I have come to the conclusion that it just doesn't work. I'm doing my source control operations using the command line now.

Comment: Well, if you are using Snow Leopard this issue will never be fixed. No newer XCode versions since 4C199 are released for Snow Leopard. If you want to fix this issue unfortunately you are forced to upgrade to Lion. Any Lion release of XCode will do it. Since I upgraded to Lion I got this error disappear. But this is still not an acceptable solution :(

Comment: This issue continues up to now. So the best way, I think, simply write to bash scripts: one for update, another for commit and place them into the dock.